# Hibernate: Prevent the mapping class from creating the table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a multi maven module project in which Module1, contains the hibernate mapping class and other modules (Module2, Module3, Module4) uses this Module1 as dependency.
As a result all the modules(Module2, Module3, Module4) create the same number of tables in there database schema.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.model.Table1"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.Table2"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.Table3"/>
    <!-- Hundreds of other tables -->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But now the situation is that, I want Module3 to not to create the Table2.
Is it possible that I add some exclusion or some configuration in Module3 that can ignore Table2 from creating but do create all others.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, Hibernate creates tables for classes that are mapped (e.g. via an hbm.xml file). If you do not map a class, the corresponding table will not be created. Please make sure to set the hbm2ddl.auto property correctly (e.g. "create" if you would like to drop and re-create the table schema on start-up) in the Hibernate configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml).

There are possibilites that might help you implement what you need or at least give you some hints:

- Have a closer look at the Configuration class in the javadocs that Hibernate offers.
- If you want to add mappings or mapping files dynamically via code: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-add-hibernate-xml-mapping-file-hbm-xml-programmatically/
- You might also want to take a closer look at the Hibernate reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

My thought would be to use a configuration file that an application reads at start-up and depending on the parameters used, adds only the needed mapping files to the Hibernate session.